# Force metadata entry on upload with modern sharepoint experience (sp online)

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, managed-metadata-column

I have a modern sharepoint site (sharepoint online) with a document library. (LibraryX)
However in LibraryX there are a few fields of metadata which are required.

The solution I am looking for is a way to leave my users unable to upload a document without entering all (correct) information. (ie; prompt them for data or expect extra data to be entered before uploading). 
The data they can choose from is also present in a list, let's say ListY. 
So preferably (if this all is possible) I would like my users when prompted for metadata to be provided with autosuggest entries from ListY.

Is this at all possible, and if so what way of solving this should I look for?

Answer (score 0):

Just make some columns require a value or apply other validation - an item can be uploaded but a user must populate all the fields to check the file in and thus make it visible.

Comment: but this will leave the possibility for users to delay entering the meta fields by any amount of time. the crux is that files uploaded must *directly* be provided with all information

Answer (score 0):

We use a separate tool that prompts users to enter metadata (companion explorer). We can  use lookup column where the value come from a list.